# Konva: why are the offsets of the layer negative?

Tags: offset, konvajs

In the [set origin coordinates for react-konva stage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47305106/set-origin-coordinates-for-react-konva-stage), it gives a helpful example about how to use offsets to set a node's origin.

The example sets the offsets of the layer to (-200, -200) so the full axes and the circle show. But I am confused by the negative offsets. I thought they should be (200, 200). But unfortunately the positive offsets make the canvas look empty. Could anyone explain how the negative offsets work?

Answer (score 1):

Coordinates start in the top-left corner of the canvas. So when you place something on your canvas, you move from top-left corner to the desired point. Simply put, the x-coordinate increases to the right and the y-coordinate increases when you go down. This system is called **window coordinates**.

**Offset** is a parameter that allows you to shift the starting point of the canvas. The direction of such movement is *opposite* to the direction of window coordinates, so notation `layer.offsetX(100)` means that you move starting point left by 100 pixels.

In the given example offsets are set to `-200`, so `(0, 0)` point (ex-start) is now on `(200, 200)`.

Hope my explanations will help you to understand window coordinates.